# Waitforpagetoload error?

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, webdriver

In my selenium webdriver code I'm trying to get my page to wait for it to load before it starts finding elements and driving them(entering text into username and password)

I tried using `driver.waitforpagetoload();` but it returned this error

```
Error   1   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'waitforpagetoload' and no extension method 'waitforpagetoload' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What type of reference to I need to add?

(coding in c#)

Answer (score 0):

I found it was helpful to use `Thread.Sleep(# of milliseconds)`, which allowed the pages to load before continuing onto the next element.

Example:

```
using System;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FireFoxTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            some code;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            more code;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hard coded sleeps are a bad thing in any automated test. Depending on how many pages you load you could end up with a ton of wasted wait time. Waiting for an element to be present is a much better way to go as  this ensures that the test only waits until the needed elements are loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because webdriver doesn't have a waitForPageToLoad function.

And you dont need it with webdriver because it will automatically block after every action, untill the page loads completely. More details here .. [WebDriver FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_WebDriver_fails_to_find_elements_/_Does_not_block_on_page_loa)

But you can have custom waits, like wait for Elements to appear on page using WebDriverWait.